# AWS Aurora Serverless v1 availability?

Tags: aws-aurora-serverless

For what engines and versions is AWS Aurora Serverless v1 still available?

I've been trying to find some combination in e.g. eu-west-1 and eu-north-1 that would allow for v1 in the serverless dropdown but haven't found any. Also tried the `aws rds describe-db-engine-versions` but couldn't quite find the filters for it

Answer (score 0):

Ah, according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.ServerlessV1.html

it is *only* for (Postgres in my case) 11.16